# 1985 Suzuki lt185 cap starter problem

Tags: suzuki, atv

I recently purchased a 1985 suzuki lt185, the guy said it needs new recoil starter, and I bought a 86 recoil starter (all the other recoil starters I came across said fit 1984-1987 I went to go put it on but the recoil starter hits the cap starter (as in block it from being fully put on.) This is the cap starter I have on my atv at the moment.

[image]

The recoil starter I bought is this one (not the exact same one)
[image]

ok The problem I am having is where the knot of the string pops out and the plastic around it, that interferes with the cap starter. Now, I am not sure if the recoil starter is compatible or if the cap starter is..

What I was thinking of doing is cutting the cap starter to look like pic below.
[image]

My question is, would that work or would I have to order new parts?

Comment: I think you need to provide all of the measurements of the inside diameter as well as outside.  Any depth clearances too.  At the end of the day, a few pictures of the components aren't enough for anyone to tell you if it can or cannot work.   Why not just procure the correct component?  They are exceedingly cheap.

Comment: Hey ducati thanks for helping me out again (nissan sentra burning oil) I think im in a weird situation, I looked up that cap starter and that is common in lt125, I think I have 125 engine with 185 frame..

Comment: That's rough.  I'm looking up some part numbers to give you some possible breadcrumbs.  I'll post a faux answer for you in a bit.

Comment: Let me know if that answer helps you to push the ball forward.

Answer (score 3):

**Engine Identification**

To identify your engine.  There should be a CC (cubic centimeters) number stamped on the side of the cylinder.  This will be below your head and above your cases.  (sorry of I'm being too elementary)

If you look closely you will see the numbers stamped into the side of the cylinder towards the bottom of the casting.  The cc number or the c3 number should help you identify the motor you have in your ATV by telling you the volume of the cylinder.

[image]

**Parts Identificaiton**

Your identification issue is a tough one.  Here are some parts fiche views for you to see if you can identify a delta between the two.

At first blush, they appear to look the same between the 125 and the 185 regarding the cup.

**LT185**

Here is the pull starter for the [1985 Suzuki LT185](http://www.suzukipartshouse.com/oemparts/a/suz/50d083e9f870022710159b9c/recoil-starter) E,F and G Model

- CUP, STARTER MODEL E/F/G Part Number 18411-24401

H Model

- CUP, STARTER MODEL H Part Number 18411-18911

**LT125**

Here is the pull starter for the [1985 Suzuki LT125](http://www.suzukipartshouse.com/oemparts/a/suz/50d082e4f8700227101599ea/recoil-starter)

Here's the part number and description
CUP, STARTER 18411-18911

Best of luck!

Comment: I was finally able to go down to where my atv was, and found out it has 178cm3 on the block, so, I am guessing its a 185?

Comment: Yes, they are always a couple of cc's under.  you have a 185.

Comment: Lol, it has 125 seat on there, well I got more for the money I guess. Anyways, I ordered cup starter that should (I really hope) fit with my recoil starter.
Also, I get spark but the atv doesn't attempt to start, what should I check next? if fuel is getting to the chamber?

Comment: Nice!  How often does that happpen?  LOL....too funny.  Good luck on that.  Hope it's correct part.

Comment: Hey man I got the atv running, but now, I ran into some problems, I over primed the carb, and there is a hole near the primer that started shooting out gas, does that mean I flood the carb? if it does then the carb keeps flooding. what could cause that? sticky needle or sticky float?

Comment: That is probably you're float bowl needle not seating properly in your float bowl.  You may need a new needle and seat. When the needle doesn't seat in the float valve fuel can fliow through this gravity operated valve. Turn you pet ok to off and replace the needle and seat.

Comment: I was also reading that the diaphram in the primer could be bad if gas is leaking from the hole, but I could be wrong. What do you mean by "turn you pet ok to off"

Comment: I meant petcock.  I was using the mobile client on an iPhone and the chat component is horrible.  tiny letters.  apologies.  My typo.  **Petcock**  is the intended word

Comment: If you are having a petcock or fuel system issue, go ahead and ask another question.  the comments on this will get out of control if we go back and forth on the flooding issue.